# Do I need my W2K3 DNS role in my Network?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, domain-controller

I currently have some internet problems - ONLY from my domain-Server (W2K3) - I have a sepeprate question for it, but I might get it resolved (I think) If I remove the DNS Role for my server. *The [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/299610/no-internet-connection-and-forward-lookup-zone-in-my-ad-dns/)

So what I am asking is:
What will happen to my intranet if I remove my Domain Controller DNS Role? How do I tell my clients that their new DNS is the ISP/Google DNS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot remove a dns controller from an active directory network if its the only dns controller on it - it's not allowed, you will also break a whole lot more than you fix even if you somehow manage to do it.

Have you checked that the dns service is correctly configured to forward dns requests its not authoritative for to other dns servers like opendns or google public dns and/or enabled the option to check root hints if forwarder nameservers unavailable? also check the network settings of your server to make sure its looking at itself for dns

Comment: thanks for the quick response. In my other Q, I have added all the logs, settings and configurations my current DC has. I am lost as to why it (the DC) does not have Internet access, while the entire intranet has.  ipconfig /all on the server, does show it looks at itself DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2
                                    80.179.52.100

Comment: btw, I don't want to expand this Q further from the original Q, as I don't want to create a 2nd thread of the problem. As for your answer, thanks. What will happen if I remove and than add back the DNS Role?

Comment: looks like you should remove the external dns servers from your servers network config, also check its gateway is set correctly, can you ping a known ip for say google.com but not lookup google.com? - in regards to removing dns role, if this is your only windows server it should not even allow you to attempt to remove the role due to AD

Comment: It was the gateway setting. It was set to 192.168.0.2  instead of 192.168.0.254

Comment: btw, I was able to delete my DNS role, as well as to reinstall it back.

Comment: Though I agree that odds are good it would not solve any problems, strictly speaking, this is incorrect.  You don't NEED Windows DNS, but you DO need a DNS server that supports Dynamic Client Updates and SRV records.  You COULD use a *nix based DNS server that supported these features.  In probably 99.99% of Windows Domain networks, you would be using a Windows DNS server.